# try to fill slice with struct and method in golang

Tags: go

I want to create a struct `movie` with the property `title` and `genre` data type `string`, then `duration` and `year` data type `integer`
then create a function with the name `addDataFilm` to add the data object from the struct to the `dataFilm` slice, then display the data:

[image: like this]

this is my code :

```
type movie struct {
    title, genre   string
    duration, year int
}

func (m movie) addDataFilm(title string, genre string, duration int, year int, dataFilm *[]string) {
    var d = strconv.Itoa(m.duration)
    var y = strconv.Itoa(m.year)
    *dataFilm = append(*dataFilm, m.title, m.genre, d, y)
}

func main(){
        var dataFim = []string{}
    var dd = movie{}

    dd.addDataFilm("LOTR", "action", 120, 1999, &dataFim)
    dd.addDataFilm("Avanger", "action", 120, 2004, &dataFim)
    dd.addDataFilm("Spiderman", "action", 120, 2004, &dataFim)
    dd.addDataFilm("Juon", "horror", 120, 2004, &dataFim)

    fmt.Println(dataFim)
}
```

all i got is :

[image: this]

any help will be appreciated. thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a [slice](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/7) of movies.  [Append](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/15) each movie to the slice. To print, [range](https://go.dev/tour/moretypes/16) over the slice and print each movie.

```
var movies []*movie
movies = append(movies, &movie{"LOTR", "action", 120, 1999})
movies = append(movies, &movie{"Avanger", "action", 120, 2004})
movies = append(movies, &movie{"Spiderman", "action", 120, 2004})
movies = append(movies, &movie{"Juon", "horror", 120, 2004})
for i, m := range movies {
    fmt.Printf("%d. Title: %s\n   Genre: %s\n   Duration: %d\n   Year: %d\n\n", i+1, m.title, m.genre, m.duration, m.year)
}
```

[Run the program on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/NR_fLHiBhvb).

The logic can be wrapped up in a type:

```
// dataFilms stores data for multiple films.
type dataFilms []*movie

func (df *dataFilms) add(title string, genre string, duration int, year int) {
    *df = append(*df, &movie{title, genre, duration, year})
}

func (df dataFilms) print() {
    for i, m := range df {
        fmt.Printf("%d. Title: %s\n   Genre: %s\n   Duration: %d\n   Year: %d\n\n", i+1, m.title, m.genre, m.duration, m.year)
    }
}

func main() {
    var df dataFilms
    df.add("LOTR", "action", 120, 1999)
    df.add("Avanger", "action", 120, 2004)
    df.add("Spiderman", "action", 120, 2004)
    df.add("Juon", "horror", 120, 2004)
    df.print()
}
```

[Run it on the playground](https://go.dev/play/p/ppHftgIJh9F).

Answer (score 1):

1. create struct new array of Movies
2. create global variable Movies to save data
3. call variable on func main

```
type Movie struct {
    Title    string
    Genre    string
    Duration int
    Year     int
}

type Movies []Movie

var dest Movies

func addDataFilm(title string, genre string, duration int, year int) Movies {

    dest = append(dest, Movie{
        Title:    title,
        Genre:    genre,
        Duration: duration,
        Year:     year,
    })

    return dest
}

func TestNumberToAlphabet(t *testing.T) {
    addDataFilm("LOTR", "action", 120, 1999)
    addDataFilm("Avanger", "action", 120, 2004)
    addDataFilm("Spiderman", "action", 120, 2004)
    addDataFilm("Juon", "horror", 120, 2004)

    fmt.Println(dest)

}
```